# ffmpeg : sws_scale not able to convert image from YUV to RGB

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, sdl

I m trying to convert my image from `YUV420P` to `RGB24` below is my code for extracting the frame and decoding it,

frame extracting

```
while(av_read_frame(avc,avpacket) == 0){
        if(avpacket->stream_index == videoStream){
            int res = avcodec_send_packet(avctx,avpacket);
            if(res == AVERROR(EAGAIN)){
                continue;
            }
            else if(res<0){
                std::cout<<"error reading packet\n";
                break;
            }
            else{
                AVFrame* avframeRGB = av_frame_alloc();
                res = avcodec_receive_frame(avctx,avframeRGB);
                if(res == AVERROR(EAGAIN)){
                    continue;
                }
                else if(res<0){
                    std::cout<<"Error reading frame";
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    ++i;
                    convertImage(&avframeRGB,avctx->pix_fmt,AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24);
                    displayImage(avframeRGB);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Function convertImage

```
void convertImage(AVFrame** frame, AVPixelFormat srcFmt, AVPixelFormat destFmt){
    AVFrame* tframe = *frame;
    struct SwsContext* swscaler = sws_getContext(tframe->width,tframe->height,srcFmt,tframe->width,tframe->height,destFmt, SWS_BILINEAR,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    AVFrame* tmp = av_frame_alloc();
    tmp->width = tframe->width;
    tmp->height = tframe->height;
    tmp->format = destFmt;
    if(av_frame_get_buffer(tmp,32) !=0)
        return;
    int res = sws_scale(swscaler,(uint8_t const * const*)tframe->data,tframe->linesize,0,tframe->height,tmp->data,tmp->linesize);
    *frame = tmp;
}
```

Before calling convertImage
avframeRGB

```
data : {0x555555988ec0 '\020' <repeats 200 times>..., 0x555555a6f940 '\200' <repeats 200 times>..., 0x555555aa9440 '\200' <repeats 200 times>..., 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}
height : 720
width : 1280
```

after calling convertImage

```
data : {0x7fffdde19040 "", 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}
height : 0
width : 0
```

I m not able to understand why my data is NULL and my height and width is 0?

ffmpeg version - 4.3.2

Comment: Check the return code of `sws_scale`. You should get a negative error value.

Comment: yes I want to know why it is happening?

Comment: What error value you get? Then dig into it.

Comment: I m not getting error value instead I m getting correct value i.e. the height of image

Comment: Something not right here... Try to update deprecated `avpicture_*` calls with the modern ones.

Comment: I have updated my code according to modern ways of allocating space for AVFrame